# Geodesics in a point mass universe

Tags: general-relativity, geodesics

This question may reflect my (lack of) knowledge about general relativity, please ask for any clarifications or note any corrections in the comments and I'll try to address them.

The Schwarzschild solution to the Einstein's field equations gives the solution to a a non-rotating, spherically symmetric uncharged mass distribution in a static vacuum. From this solution, we can compute geodesics from one point to another.

Is it possible (analytically or numerically) to compute the geodesics from one point to another under the influence of a set of static point masses? The point masses can assume arbitrary geometry, but like the Schwarzschild problem they are uncharged and non-rotating.

Comment: A more basic question is whether there is a solution to Einstein's equations corresponding to a set of static point masses.  I'd bet that any work done on even this question is numerical much less solving for geodesics in such a geometry.

Comment: Thanks @joshphysics, I figured the solution would be extremely difficult but I'm completely out of my element here. I'd be happy for a numerical solution, I think I'd learn a lot reading over the algorithm.

Comment: Well, this is conceptually distinct from your original question, but it is related and interesting http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem_in_general_relativity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are **no** *static* solutions for multiple uncharged point masses. This fact becomes apparent, if we note that the point mass initially at rest will start moving in the gravitational field of the rest of masses.

So if one is looking for a *static* spacetime with several point masses, then one have to provide additional force to hold the masses stationary and counteract the gravitational attraction.

One such possibility are the **Israel-Khan solutions**, which describe finitely many collinear Schwarzschild black holes in static equilibrium. The forces holding them apart arise from conical deficits in the form of 'struts' between the black holes, or cosmic strings extending to infinity.

Another mechanism to counteract gravitational attraction is electrostatic repulsion. This leads us to **Majumdar-Papapetrou** (MP) solutions describing the set of *charged* extremal (which means that charge is equal to mass in natural units) black holes.

The geodesics in this class of metric have been studied (along with trajectories of charged particles). 
Here is the paper describing the chaotic dynamics of a test particle moving in such a spacetime:

> Cornish, N.J., Dettmann, C.P. &  Frankel, N.E.  *Fractal basins and chaotic trajectories in multi-black hole space-times*. Phys. Rev. D50:618-621 (1994), [DOI:10.1103/PhysRevD.50.R618](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.50.R618), [arXiv:gr-qc/9402027](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9402027).

Besides providing the equations of motion for the test particle (it can also be charged) in the MP metric (which are then integrated numerically), this paper describes the previous work done in the field:

> Chandrasekhar [12] and Contopoulos [13], [14] have investigated the timelike and null
>   geodesics of the two black hole system from the point of view of the periodic orbits and
>   the weak field limit. For particles with elliptic (bound) energies the trajectories fall into several categories. There are stable periodic and quasiperiodic orbits, chaotic orbits trapped between periodic orbits, trajectories which fall into one or other of the black holes, and chaotic trajectories which lie on the boundary of these regions. This structure, together with the fact that the weak field limit is integrable, makes the MP geodesics problem a particularly interesting example of chaos in General Relativity.

So, if you are interested in analytical results concerning these metrics you could turn to this referenced works.

Comment: Thank you for the reference and the great answer. I admit I hadn't considered the fact that the masses themselves wouldn't have static positions relative to each  other. Is it possible though to consider something like an _instantaneous geodesic_, i.e. the geodesic made by connecting the series geodesics over a small differential of space between two points? I envision something like a calculus of variations problem, the path that would connect the two points over the shortest spacetime.

Comment: You could always 'slice' nonstatic spacetime into spacelike layers and solve geodesic equations inside each layer. The problem with that, is that the particles generally wont be moving along such lines. Moreover such slicing (for instance, by selecting hypersurface of t=const) is not unique.